# Получить value из элемента листа JS

Tags: javascript

[image: a]

Как правильно вытащить текст value из input, если нет id у этого элемента?

Пробовал так, но ощущение, что двигаюсь не туда:

```js
var btn = document.createElement('button')
document.body.appendChild(btn)

const ttr = document.createElement("div");

      ttr.setAttribute("class", "saver");

      class test {
        constructor(btn, inputs) {
          this.btn = document.querySelector(btn);
          this.inputs = document.querySelectorAll(inputs);

          this.letes = "";
          this.main();
        }

        main() {
          this.inputs.forEach((item) => {
            this.letes += item.innerHTML;
          });

          this.btn.onclick = () => {
            console.log(this.letes);
          };
        }
      }

      const obj = new test("button", "input");
```

Comment: Как ни странно, для получения `value` надо использовать свойство `value` а не `innerHTML`

Comment: @Grundy, пробовал, пустое поле возвращает

Comment: если поменять `innerHTML` на `value` + добавить таки в дом инпуты, то все работает как нужно

Comment: @Grundy *this.letes += item.inputs.value;*, правильно понял?

Comment: @Jefoce, да, только тут у тебя опечатка, `item` это и есть `input` у тебя, и ты у него сначала брал  `innerHTML`, почему сейчас начал брать `inputs`? Надо просто заменить innerHTML на value

Comment: @Grundy пробовал item.value, но возвращает пустой letes

Comment: Значит неправильно пробовал. Отредактируй сниппет в вопросе, чтобы был [mcve] который у тебя уже есть.

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, уже получилось решить проблему)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несколько вариантов...

```js
/* Первый инпут( [0] ), который находится внутри id="file_1" */
let x = document.getElementById('file_1').getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

/* Первый найденный инпут внутри id="file_1" */
let y = document.querySelectorAll('#file_1 input')[0];

/* Только первый на странице инпут, с value="test-bubu", тут нельзя добавлять [0], [1]...*/
let z = document.querySelector('input[value="test-bubu"]');

console.log( x.value );
console.log( y.value );
console.log( z.value );
```

```html
<output id="list">
  <ol>
    <ol id="file_1">
      <h3>FileName</h3>
      <dl></dl>
      <div class="textarea">
        <dt></dt>
        <dt>
          <input readonly value="test-bubu" type="text">
        </dt>
      </div>
    </ol>
  </ol>
</output>
```

Но не понятно, почему нельзя туда просто добавить id...

P.s. выкладывать код в виде картинки - садизм... не ннада так)))

Comment: Спасибо, не сработало, лог:

save.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null
    at new test (save.js:19)
    at save.js:34

Comment: "Но не понятно, почему нельзя туда просто добавить id..." - не мой html, я через расширение делаю

Comment: "P.s. выкладывать код в виде картинки - садизм... не ннада так)))" хорошо

Comment: Значит у вас скрипт загружается еще до того, как браузер успел "прочитать" HTML. Нужно либо разместить его где-то ниже HTML, либо разместить внутри общей функции... `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ /* код, размещенный здесь, сработает после загрузки страницы */ });` — или, если скрипт добавляется через внешнюю ссылку, использовать `<script src="..." defer></script>`

Comment: Спасибо, сработало)

Answer (score -1):

Можно же поставить id и использовать document.getElementById

можно вот так
      var text = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
      var val=text.value;
      alert(val)

можно поставить на инпут событие onchange и в функцию посылать значение

Comment: Спасибо, попробую